# curl_error couldn't open file

Tags: php, curl, telegram

i want to send photo in telegram with api method
my php class is [TelegramBotPHP](https://github.com/Eleirbag89/TelegramBotPHP)

my php code

```
$img = curl_file_create('test.png','image/png'); 
$content = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, 'photo' => $img );
$telegram->sendPhoto($content);
```

Return Error

```
ok:         False
curl_error_code:        26
curl_error:     couldn't open file "test.png"
```

Helper for Uploading file using CURL

```
if (!function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
    function curl_file_create($filename, $mimetype = '', $postname = '')
    {
        return "@$filename;filename="
        .($postname ?: basename($filename))
        .($mimetype ? ";type=$mimetype" : '');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the image in same folder than your php script ?

Comment: yes image is in the same folder